# Control points transformation

Tags: javascript, typescript, three.js, floating-point

I want to display **control points** (THREE.Vector3 with 0 z coordinate) on a **canvas**. These control points has values less than 1, and the canvas has a 200px height and 400px width. So because of this, I **transform these points** (multiply each with 100) before displaying on the canvas, and after changing its position I **reverse the transformation** by dividing it by 100. I reverse the transformation because the original positions come from an engine and I have to write it back.

Can someone explain me why this transformation doesn't work?

```
const transformControlPointsForDisplay = (controlPoints: THREE.Vector3[]) => controlPoints.map(cp => new THREE.Vector3(
    cp.x * 100.0,
    cp.y * 100.0,
    cp.z * 100.0
));
const reverseTransformControlPoints = (controlPoints: THREE.Vector3[]) => controlPoints.map(cp => new THREE.Vector3(
    Number((cp.x * 1.0 / 100).toFixed(10)),
    Number((cp.y * 1.0 / 100).toFixed(10)),
    Number((cp.z * 1.0 / 100).toFixed(10)),
));
```

Comment: What DOES it do?  I do see that you are multiplying by 10, not by 100.

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes, you're right, it's just a typo, I fixed it. I have control points from an engine. I want to display these on a canvas, but the control points have values less than 1 and the canvas has 400x200 size, so I transform the points to have greater values to be visible on the canvas. After I displayed it on the canvas, there's a logic implemented which handles that the points can be movable. After changing positions, I have to write these back in the engine, so I want to reverse the transformation, but in this way it's always set the values to 0.

Comment: Why are you doing `toFixed`?  That converts to a string, which seems not to be what you want.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre]. And consider not overwriting the stored values with transformed numbers at all; use the transformed numbers only for display.